# How to set each item's selection color of QTableWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'd like to have different selection color when an item is selected. But the `QTableWidget::item:selected{ background-color: }` only works when there is only one item selected, otherwise all selected items will have the same selection color. So is there a way to make every item have individual selection color?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.MainWindow=MainWindow
        self.MainWindow.resize(300, 100)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        """table """
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("red"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("blue"))
        self.tableWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.ChangeSelectionColor)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def ChangeSelectionColor(self):
        try:
            for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
                col=item.column()
            self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item:selected{ background-color: %s }"%color_list[col])
        except UnboundLocalError:
            pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    color_list=['red','blue']
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

One selection works good.

[image]

Multiple selection just applies the color to all items selected. I want the left one to be red once selected.

Comment: On what does the color depend?

Comment: @eyllanesc the `color_list` defined in `main`.  When column=i, the selection color of it should be `color_list[i]` .

Comment: I think you have not understood my question, I say you have a table of 2 rows and 3 columns, what would be the colors, what should each cell have when it is selected?

Comment: @eyllanesc The question I posted is just a simplification. In my project, every item's color is stored in a list as well.

Comment: I want to place a solid answer, let's say the list is of length 5 and 6 items are selected, what color should the sixth item have?

Comment: @eyllanesc  I think the selection color every item supposed to have is not so important.  What really matters is that each selection color should be independent when in multiple selection. You can do it whatever you like.

Comment: @eyllanesc I think I misunderstood your question before. Every item's selection color is defined before it's added to the table. So the color list is always the same length of the number of items in table.

Comment: Try with my solution :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use qss in this case is not appropriate because they have many limitations, it is appropriate to implement a delegate, in this case a class that inherits from QStyledItemDelegate. But before that we must save the color information through the setData method of QTableWidgetItem:

```
it = QTableWidgetItem("some_text")
it.setData(Qt.UserRole, some_color)
```

Then the paint method of `QStyledItemDelegate` is overwritten and the selection color is changed:

```
class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        color = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
        option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, color)
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

Then the delegate is established:

```
your_qtablewidget.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate())
```

A complete example I show it below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStyledItemDelegate, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QStyle
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import qrand, Qt

class ColorDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        color = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
        option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, color)
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


def fun(n_rows, n_columns):
    return [[QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256) for i in range(n_rows)] for j in range(n_columns)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    n_rows, n_columns = 10, 10
    colors = fun(n_rows, n_columns)
    w = QTableWidget()
    w.setColumnCount(n_columns)
    w.setRowCount(n_columns)
    for i in range(w.rowCount()):
        for j in range(w.columnCount()):
            it = QTableWidgetItem("{}-{}".format(i, j))
            it.setData(Qt.UserRole, colors[i][j])
            w.setItem(i, j, it)
    w.setItemDelegate(ColorDelegate())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. You are the best!

Comment: I still have a confusion though. The font color automatically changes to white once selected. How to avoid that and keep the font color not changing?

Comment: you would add the line:

    option.palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, color)

making color, whatever text color you want at that point.